# Node Module (robotjs) was compiled against a different Node.js version

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, vscode-extensions, robotjs

So I'm trying to build a simple VS Code extension but after I finally found the right modul to use I can't get it to run corectly.

After pressing F5 to test the extension i just get the message:

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.vs-code-media-player' failed: The module '\\? 
\c:\Users\myName\Google Drive\03_Persoenlich\Programming\VS Code Extensions\vs-code- 
media-player\node_modules\robotjs\build\Release\robotjs.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 83. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 89. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`)..
```

I tried:

- npm rebuild
- uprgading npm
- downgrading npm
- installing another module version
- create a new project
- updating node

But nothing worked so far.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit 1:
I tried using different node versions to compile, but node 16.0.0 uses NODE_MODULE_VERSION 93 and node 15.14.0 uses NODE_MODULE_VERSION 88 but there is nothing in between.

Comment: Try deleting everything in `node_modules`

Comment: I deleted everything in that folder and reinstalled it with `npm i` but still get same message.